Random aborts of reporting service data-driven subscriptions - Cannot read the next data row for the dataset DataSet1
My company is running Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 on one machine and it is where the ReportServer database is stored. The Reporting Services is integrated with SharePoint service, which is installed in another machine. Both servers are increasingly busy over the years.
We have a data-driven subscription that generates monthly invoices for each invoice number. Typically there are around 30 to 40 invoices to be generated on each run.
In recent months we found that some invoices, may be 3 to 6, failed to generate from that data-driven subscription. The log says that:

Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException:
Cannot read the next data row for the dataset DataSet1

As each invoice is generated using the same stored procedure (hence the same SQL code) on DataSet1, yet not all of the invoices failed, it seems to me that the error is not due to the stored procedure itself.
Could someone point me to the right directions on solving this issue? Thanks in advance.
Sample outputs from the SSRS trace log:

processing!WindowsService_1!59c58!04/08/2024-18:40:18:: e ERROR: An
exception has occurred in data set 'DataSet1'. Details:
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException:
Cannot read the next data row for the dataset DataSet1. --->
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A severe error occurred on the
current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded. Operation
cancelled by user.
processing!WindowsService_1!59c58!04/08/2024-18:40:18:: i INFO:
DataPrefetch abort handler called for Report with ID=. Aborting data
sources ... processing!WindowsService_1!59c58!04/08/2024-18:40:18:: e
ERROR: Throwing
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingAbortedException:
,
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingAbortedException:
An error has occurred during report processing. --->
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException:
Cannot read the next data row for the dataset DataSet1. --->
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A severe error occurred on the
current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded. Operation
cancelled by user.    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---;
processing!WindowsService_1!59c58!04/08/2024-18:40:18:: w WARN: Data
source 'BIDW': Report processing has been aborted.
processing!WindowsService_1!59c58!04/08/2024-18:40:18:: e ERROR:
Throwing
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingAbortedException:
,
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingAbortedException:
An error has occurred during report processing. --->
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException:
Cannot read the next data row for the dataset DataSet1. --->
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A severe error occurred on the
current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded. Operation
cancelled by user.    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---;
library!WindowsService_1!59c58!04/08/2024-18:40:18:: w WARN:
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingAbortedException:
An error has occurred during report processing. --->
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException:
Cannot read the next data row for the dataset DataSet1. --->
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A severe error occurred on the
current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded. Operation
cancelled by user.
library!WindowsService_1!59c58!04/08/2024-18:40:18:: i INFO:
Initializing EnableExecutionLogging to 'True'  as specified in Server
system properties.
subscription!WindowsService_1!59c58!04/08/2024-18:40:18:: i INFO:
Failure writing file  :
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.RSException: An
error has occurred during report processing. --->
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingAbortedException:
An error has occurred during report processing. --->
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException:
Cannot read the next data row for the dataset DataSet1. --->
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A severe error occurred on the
current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded. Operation
cancelled by user..
subscription!WindowsService_1!59c58!04/08/2024-18:40:18:: i INFO:
Error writing file ha001_202403016 to path
http://www.example.com/bi/Reports/SIP/Sales/Report Output/HA 001
notification!WindowsService_1!59c58!04/08/2024-18:40:18:: e ERROR:
Error occured processing subscription
2b3660a2-e604-4b71-99cc-74d2a11408f7: Failure writing file  : An error
has occurred during report processing..
processing!WindowsService_1!59b58!04/08/2024-18:40:18:: e ERROR:
Throwing
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException:
,
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException:
Cannot read the next data row for the dataset DataSet1. --->
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A severe error occurred on the
current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded. Operation
cancelled by user.    at
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
Boolean breakConnection)    at
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
stateObj)    at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior
runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
stateObj)


Not sure how you are hoping we can help with such minimal information. You're going to have to dig in and debug. It sounds to me that the method of obtaining the list of invoices to send it getting disconnected mid-run.

Hmmm but Dataset1 sounds like your report not your subscription, so maybe the database connection is breaking while the report tries to obtain the invoice

Are you getting any additional information in the error log? "Cannot read the next row" is often associated with another message, for example a timeout, or a data type conversion error.

This might be a good opportunity to look at your stack and check the support end dates of sql server 2008 etc

@DaleK; @allmhuran
Additional SSRS trace log output has been included in my original post. Please advice further. I am happy to supply more information you need if I could. The subscription is a data-driven one which runs the report every time for each invoice number. The report executes a stored procedure to produce that "Dataset1". The server hosting the SQL server is currently very overloaded. Could that be a reason for the database disconnection you have mentioned? How could I verify this?

"Operation cancelled by user" looks like a timeout to me.
